# String allocation in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mono

Suppose I have the following code which assigns a string to a Android.Widget.Button or a UIKit.UIButton:

```
btn.SetText("Some text");
```

Does this mean the app has two strings in memory? One in managed (Xamarin .NET) and the other one in the unnmanged (native iOS/Android)?

It sounds like the app ends up with a duplicate of the string in memory.

What I know is that in .NET there's a intern pool for string literals. Does this apply to Xamarin .NET too? How are strings handled under the hood in Xamarin?

Comment: ,From [What is Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin),Xamarin is built on top of Mono, for example, I create Button and set text,I guess that it is saved in the java String Pool.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thanks, I'm aware Xamarin is built on Mono. But how can we be sure the string is not duplicate in memory?

Comment: I mean, how do we know for sure whether the string is duplicated or not, Can we profile the app maybe

Comment: whether the string is duplicated or not, I don't get any info about this so far, but I will still search this info.